# What is the distribution of the intensity of natural electromagnetic field on Earth based on frequency?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life

I was arguing with someone about the health effects of Wifi router and one of the things that came to mind was this statement:

> "The intensity of EM field from Wifi device is negligible compared to the natural sources."

For some reason I believe this statement is correct, but I couldn't find any sources to back it up. There is probably some EM field (white noise) on all frequencies we are using (causing grain on the TV, static on the radio etc), most of it coming from outer space (mainly Sun), some deflected by magnetosphere, some absorbed in the atmosphere. 
But what is the intensity of this natural radiation? I would expect that some data must exists - some frequency/intensity plot, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

The intensity of sunlight at the surface of the earth is roughly 1 kW/m$^2$. Your wifi router has a power level not to exceed 4 W (by FCC rules). That means that at a distance of a few cm, the power level will be lower than sunlight (which is a reasonable definition of "natural EM background").

Of course the biological effect of electromagnetic radiation is a function of frequency; but I hope the above simple analogy shows that this is a silly argument (without defining the frequency band, and deciding "which is more dangerous", you really have nowhere to go). Being in sunlight all day is sure to give you skin cancer more quickly than the EM exposure you get from sitting in the same room as a wifi router (there may be many other factors influencing your health in either situation - but the wifi router should not be high on your list)

For kicks, I calculated the black body spectrum as a function of wavelength, taking it all the way to the wavelength of microwave radiation (about 12 cm for 2.4 GHz). The plot is below: it shows about 20 orders of magnitude difference between the radiation due to the sun at the peak, and at RF. And a colder body (like the cosmic background radiation) will give a lower value at all wavelengths. Of course you might want to correct for the fact that the sun is covering only a small fraction of the sky - at 0.5° subtended angle, it covers about $4\cdot 10^{-5}$ of the sky - so if you had "cosmic background" of the magnitude of the sun coming from every part of the sky, it would still be 15 orders of magnitude lower than the peak intensity of the sun. I still argue that you can safely ignore the health effect.

[image]

Comment: But that's just visible light. I was looking for some information like "the intensity of natural EM radiation is X for frequencies 2-3 GHz" to prove that even if those frequencies were harmful, the effect of radiation from Wifi router is negligible.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj If that's your interest, then the statement cannot be true.  If that statement were true, then the WiFi signal would be lost in the naturally occurring noise.  (You might want to edit your question to be more clear.  I'm still not sure I'm interpreting the question as you intend.)

Comment: It is definitely possible to transmit data even if the noise has higher intensity than the signal. At least when the background noise is uniform.
Edit: I've changed the title to be more precise(but I'm not sure I've made it more clear)

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj  I don't know exactly what you mean by "uniform".  Nonetheless,  you might be able to extract the signal when it's *slightly* below the noise level, but generally you cannot.  Certainly WiFi would not operate in that regime.

Comment: The problem is that "damage" might occur over the range from 2 to 3 GHz, but a narrow band transmit/receive system, while having a "high" power at 2.4000 GHz, might have far less power than the integral of background from 2 to 3 GHz. As such, the question you seem to want answered is not well-formed.

Comment: Floris: I still don't see anything wrong with my question. "high" power at 2.4000 GHz, might have far less power than the integral of background from 2 to 3 GHz - that's basically what I want to prove. I just chose to phrase the question more generally. If there was this intensity/frequency plot of natural background radiation, that would be awesome. But judging from the responses, I guess there's no such thing.

Answer (score -2):

There is the Microwave Background Radiation which is at a temperature of 2.72548 Kelvin.

Also there is the Earth's magnetic field which is about 40 microteslas.